# Unable to run a VB script

Tags: dom, vbscript, autologin

I am just trying to run a VB script to do auto login function.
I am unable to run the script as as i am receiving below  exception
**"The object invoked had disconnected from its client"**

Code/script:

```
Const strURL = "YOUR URL HERE"
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.Navigate2 strURL
Do While objIE.Busy
WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 39000
objIE.document.getElementById("username").Value = "USERNAME"
objIE.document.getElementById("password_input").Value = "PASSS"
objIE.document.getElementById("Login").click
```

Comment: And on what line of the code do you get this exception?  Will help to determine which object is having the problem...

Comment: objIE.document.getElementById("username").Value = "USERNAME"   10th line